# How to injecting jenkins variable to robot script report name

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

I have a text file on my linux machine which stores a integer value. I want that integer value to be in my robot results report file.

I tried this:

```
${FILE,path="/home/ubuntu/Build_number.txt"}
```

and its properly printing the integer in email content of jenkins but when I give it in robot command (which is on execute shell in jenkins), it does not print any value.

Robot command as:

```
robot -r report_${FILE,path="/home/ubuntu/Build_number.txt"} Login.robot
```

Actual: Running this command generates a report file of name report_.html

Expected:
report_(integer value in Build_number.txt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, this question to Linux/Bash forum. Bash has another syntax what you use.
Correct command is:

```sh
robot -r report_$(cat /home/ubuntu/Build_number.txt) Login.robot
```